# @firebase/firestore: Firestore (8.3.3): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

After having added eslint and not having changed code, I ran my application that was working perfectly fine yesterday. I ended up getting the following error:

```
[2021-04-09T04:47:33.960Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (8.3.3): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid resource field value in the request.
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
```

I saw some other stackoverflow posts and github issues as well, and most seem to have encountered the same issue before. I've attempted some of the proposed solutions - downgrading firebase, checking my internet, etc - and nothing seems to do the trick.

Comment: I got it to work. It had to do with my nodejs server file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow .. Post your answer to help new people in Stcak Overflow :)

Comment: @LeonardKee can you post why you were having this error as an answer? I haven't found this exact error anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

(Edit — TLDR: If you're seeing this error, double check that the server config vars in your code match your runtime vars in nuxt.config.ts match your .env match the Firebase Project Settings)

Thanks, this helped me resolve the same error code in my app as yours. I looked into my server config and realized I didn't have all the Firebase config vars from Firebase Project Settings in my project's runtime config (nuxt.config.ts and .env file).

Was not easy to figure this out so I hope the info helps someone. It resolved that error for me, but now I'm getting `code=permission-denied 7 PERMISSION_DENIED` error instead so

Good luck!

Comment: Fully resolved this issue. The root cause was overlooking the commas at the end of each line of Firebase config in the code snippet after I pasted into my .env to get the values. 

Thanks again!